# Are external requests blocked on actions on google simulator?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am developing an Actions on Google app with a Dialogflow integration. When testing in the Dialogflow simulator with a common request call I get a response, that is, the Uri I have passed is found, executes and returns a response. Doing exactly the same in the Actions on Google simulator creates this error.

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND abc.eu.auth0.com abc.eu.auth0.com:443
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'abc.eu.auth0.com',
host: 'abc.eu.auth0.com',
port: 443 }
```

The code looks like this

```
let options = {
    uri: 'https://abc.eu.auth0.com/userinfo/',
    headers: {
       authorization: 'Bearer ' + _accessToken,
   }
};

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        // output error, body, response, do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

`request` is the request package.

So the question is, are there any limitations in the Actions on Google simulator/test mode? (I get the same error when talking to Google Assistant on my phone when signed in with developer account).

Comment: Are you using the Inline Editor in Dialogflow fulfillment as a webhook?

Comment: Hi, no I develop it locally and publish it using firebase.

Comment: If your firebase payment plan is Spark Outbound networking (HTTP requests) are limited to Google services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no limitations on the simulator - it is just talking to your webhook backend and has no idea what the operating environment is.

If you're using the built-in fulfillment editor in Dialogflow, or if you've deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions, then you need to check which plan you're using.

The default is the "spark" plan, which is free, but which has the limitation that it can't access web or network services outside of Google's.

You can upgrade to the "blaze" plan, which allows network access, but which requires you to register a credit card and charges for use. *However*, even on the blaze plan, there is a free tier which they won't bill you for. This free tier is generally enough for experimenting, initial development, and use under early deployment. Once you are deployed, the Google Assistant has offers for cloud credits which should offset this as well.